# Excel VBA module does not ignore blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA module I got online to count cell with conditional formatting. This module has an issue in that it returns an error if in the range it is counting, a cell is either blank or does not have a conditional format rule. The module is:

```
Function CountCFCells(rng As Range, C As Range)
Dim i As Single, j As Long, k As Long
Dim chk As Boolean, Str1 As String, CFCELL As Range
chk = False
For i = 1 To rng.FormatConditions.Count
    If rng.FormatConditions(i).Interior.ColorIndex = C.Interior.ColorIndex Then
        chk = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
j = 0
k = 0
If chk = True Then
    For Each CFCELL In rng
        Str1 = CFCELL.FormatConditions(i).Formula1
        Str1 = Application.ConvertFormula(Str1, xlA1, xlR1C1)
        Str1 = Application.ConvertFormula(Str1, xlR1C1, xlA1, , ActiveCell.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells(k + 1))
        If Evaluate(Str1) = True Then j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    Next CFCELL
Else
CountCFCells = "Color not found"
Exit Function
End If
CountCFCells = j
End Function
```

When I call this function using `=CountCFCells(A1:A30, B1)`, I want it to ignore any cells don't have any conditional formating rules or data (type is number). What is the best way to disregard any cells in the range that do not have conditional formatting rules or data?

Comment: what have you tried so far? You ask for the best way, have you figured out any way to do it?

Comment: No, i have no solution so far. The code works even if the cell is black as long as there are conditional formatting rules applied. But, I would like it to ignore cells without conditional formatting rules applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you have a few errors. The code isn't designed to handle a cell ("CFCELL") where conditional formatting is nonexistent (blank cells should actually be okay in the above code so long as they're assigned a rule).

So, let's try this instead:

```
Function CountCFCells(rng As Range, C As Range) As Long
Dim i As Single, j As Long, Total As Long
Dim CFCELL As Range
Dim Match_CI As Long

j = 0
Match_CI = C.Interior.ColorIndex

For Each CFCELL In rng
    If CFCELL.FormatConditions.Count > 0 And Len(CFCELL) > 0 Then
        If DisplayedColor(CFCELL) = Match_CI Then
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
Next CFCELL

Total = j
CountCFCells = Total

End Function


Function DisplayedColor(Cell As Range, Optional CellInterior As Boolean = True, _
                        Optional ReturnColorIndex As Long = True) As Long
  Dim X As Long, Test As Boolean, CurrentCell As String
  If Cell.Count > 1 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError - 999, , "Only single cell references allowed for 1st argument."
  CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Address
  For X = 1 To Cell.FormatConditions.Count
    With Cell.FormatConditions(X)
      If .Type = xlCellValue Then
        Select Case .Operator
          Case xlBetween:      Test = Cell.Value >= Evaluate(.Formula1) And Cell.Value <= Evaluate(.Formula2)
          Case xlNotBetween:   Test = Cell.Value <= Evaluate(.Formula1) Or Cell.Value >= Evaluate(.Formula2)
          Case xlEqual:        Test = Evaluate(.Formula1) = Cell.Value
          Case xlNotEqual:     Test = Evaluate(.Formula1) <> Cell.Value
          Case xlGreater:      Test = Cell.Value > Evaluate(.Formula1)
          Case xlLess:         Test = Cell.Value < Evaluate(.Formula1)
          Case xlGreaterEqual: Test = Cell.Value >= Evaluate(.Formula1)
          Case xlLessEqual:    Test = Cell.Value <= Evaluate(.Formula1)
        End Select
      ElseIf .Type = xlExpression Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Cell.Select
        Test = Evaluate(.Formula1)
        Range(CurrentCell).Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      End If
      If Test Then
        If CellInterior Then
          DisplayedColor = IIf(ReturnColorIndex, .Interior.ColorIndex, .Interior.color)
        Else
          DisplayedColor = IIf(ReturnColorIndex, .Font.ColorIndex, .Font.color)
        End If
        Exit Function
      End If
    End With
  Next
  If CellInterior Then
    DisplayedColor = IIf(ReturnColorIndex, Cell.Interior.ColorIndex, Cell.Interior.color)
  Else
    DisplayedColor = IIf(ReturnColorIndex, Cell.Font.ColorIndex, Cell.Font.color)
  End If
End Function
```

This will count all cells which have conditional formatting rules applied to them containing data within the selected range. It will only match entries which are the same color as cell you select second in the formula. In this case, I made it so it counts user-entered zero's as a value (will not skip it if someone actually entered a zero).

Comment: I want the code to handle cells without conditional formating. I have columns of varying length, and each cell with data has 3 conditional formating rules. Each rule changes the color of the cell. The code i was using counted the number of (for example) purple, green, & blue cells. So, you are on to something here, but really i still want input a range and a cell that matches the conditional formating that I can looking for in the range. From that, I want the count of the purple (or green or blue) cells. And, I don't want an error when the range includes a cell without conditional formatting.

Comment: "blank cells should actually be okay in the above code so long as they're assigned a rule" - This is true

Comment: My re-written code can already handle cells without conditional formatting rules (it skips them). I've added the second argument back in, which will only match on a selected color as it did originally.

Comment: This code doesn't work, and I think it does not work because counting the color fill is different than counting the color fill that results from conditional formatting. If you have a cell with white color fill, a value of 8 and a conditional format rule that changes the color fill to red if the value is > 10, the cell color fill will be red, but the actual color fill is still white.

Comment: Conditional formatting is tricky- the code didn't work because it turns out that `.DisplayFormat` can't actually be used in a function. See my updated response.

Comment: I don't know if this code is working.I cannot get it to evaluate without an error. Why is the second argument optional? In my original code, the first argument is the range of cells in which the conditional formatting will be counted, and argument 2 is a cell in which the conditional formatting that i am counting in the range is true and applied.

Comment: Ok, I see there are two functions. This appears to have solved the question! Thank you